# Show objects from array which contain only a specific property

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, bson

I'm new to mongodb and I'd like to help me if you can. I have a collection of documents (songs) like the following:

```
{
   title: 'song number 1',
   duration: '3:23',
   text: [
           {chords: 'some chords'},
           {lyrics: 'some lyrics'},
           {chords: 'again chords'},
           {lyrics: 'again lyrics'}
    ]

},
{
   title: 'song number 23',
   duration: '4:22',
   text: [
           {chords: 'some chords'},
           {lyrics: 'some lyrics'},
           {chords: 'again chords'},
           {lyrics: 'again lyrics'}
    ]

}
```

I want to retrieve for every document (song) ONLY the chords from the text array.
Any ideas please?

Comment: can you add the result you expect to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation query *filters* the `text` array elements where the `chords` field exists or not empty or not null.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: {
          text: { 
              $filter: {
                  input: "$text",
                     as: "txt",
                    cond: {
                             $gt: [ { $strLenCP: { $ifNull: [ "$$txt.chords", "" ] } },  0 ] 
                          }
              }
          }
      }
  }
] )
```

The result will look like this (with the first document from the question post as input):

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "title" : "song number 1",
        "duration" : "3:23",
        "text" : [
                {
                        "chords" : "some chords"
                },
                {
                        "chords" : "again chords"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! I needed this query

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$text"},
    {$match: {"text.chords":{$exists:true}}},
    {$project: {'text.chords':1}}
]).pretty()
```

This query shows only the chords subdocuments of every song, not the lyrics.
The key of the query (I think) is $unwind.
Thank you everyone for your answers and the help.

Comment: Good try. But, using a filter with project is more efficient way to filter the array elements within a document.